# How to convert `mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2` tiles to heightmap tiles?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox, mapbox-gl, osm.pbf

`Mapbox` provides a kindle of map tiles--`mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2` which is stored in `pbf` format and saved in `mvt` suffix. The height data is represented by contour (line).
I want to generate terrain with satellite texture and this height data in `Unity3D`. How could I convert this `pbf` data to a height map(a pixel for a height value)?

There is an example
`https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2/12/1171/1566.jpg?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoib2xlb3RpZ2VyIiwiYSI6ImZ2cllZQ3cifQ.2yDE9wUcfO_BLiinccfOKg`

And the mvt file
`https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2/12/1171/1566.mvt?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoib2xlb3RpZ2VyIiwiYSI6ImZ2cllZQ3cifQ.2yDE9wUcfO_BLiinccfOKg`

And the document of Mapbox:
`https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/mapbox-terrain/`

`https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/`

Answer (score 1):

MapBox have buid a Unity3d package: MapBox-Unity-SDK

SDK here : https://www.mapbox.com/unity/

Just click download. 
This is an asset you can open in Unity directly.

Launch Unity3d, goto Menu>Assets>ImportPackage>CustomPackage
and select your downloaded file.

It will unpack some files and the folders, you will find into some exemples scene files to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The current vector terrain layer isn't designed to be turned into a heightmap: we've processed terrain into elevation contours and lines, so turning those back into raw data would be difficult (much like doing the opposite: we do a lot of processing because it would also be difficult to transfer raw data and derive visual data).

A new and improved vector terrain model that supports your usecase is on the way, but we've also introduced [RGB terrain](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/terrain-rgb/), which was actually designed specifically to address cases like Unity - decoding the RGB-encoded elevation tiles tends to be much simpler in software.